# I'm trying to create an infinite vertical scrolling background with SpirteKit, however I can't seem to get the code to work

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

The loop isn't timed correctly and resets too quickly. The looped image is also cut off showing only a fraction of it rather than the full looped background image stitched to the previous one.

I've attempted playing around with the .position, .size, and the SKAction values, but I just can't seem to tweak it to where it works properly.

```
func scrollingBackground() {
    let BGTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Background")

    for i in 0 ... 1 {
        let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: BGTexture)
        background.zPosition = -30
        background.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        background.size = CGSize(width: (frame.size.width), height: (frame.size.height))
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -BGTexture.size().height + (BGTexture.size().height + (BGTexture.size().height * CGFloat(i))))
        addChild(background)

        let scrollUp = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: BGTexture.size().height, duration: 20)
        let scrollReset = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -BGTexture.size().height, duration: 0)
        let scrollLoop = SKAction.sequence([scrollUp, scrollReset])
        let scrollForever = SKAction.repeatForever(scrollLoop)

        background.run(scrollForever)
    }
```

I hoping to get a seamless infinite background loop that runs indefinitely rather than this jumpy mess I currently have. I might add that my background image isn't originally sized perfectly to the devices, but I'm wanting to make sure my background fits to all iPhone devices.

Comment: you are using width when you mean height

Comment: That's my bad, copied the old code before I changed that value to height. It still didn't fix it though.

Answer (score 0):

Your first BG is at y = 0,  Your second BG is at y = height.  I am assuming that you are on anchor point 0.5 0.5, which would make height / 2 off screen.  Your action moves BG 1 exactly to where it is off screen, then bumps back to 0.  Your BG2 starts off screen, continues to move off screen, then when it hits 2 * height, resets to 1 * height, thus never appears on the screen.  This is going to give the appearance of a black bar at the bottom, because BG2 is never drawn.  Multiply your `i` by negative height instead, and that should cause the BG2 to appear on the bottom instead.

```
func scrollingBackground() {
    let BGTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Background")

    for i in 0 ... 1 {
        let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: BGTexture)
        background.zPosition = -30
        background.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        background.size = CGSize(width: (frame.size.width), height: (frame.size.height))
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -BGTexture.size().height + (BGTexture.size().height + (-BGTexture.size().height * CGFloat(i))))
        addChild(background)

        let scrollUp = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: BGTexture.size().height, duration: 20)
        let scrollReset = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -BGTexture.size().height, duration: 0)
        let scrollLoop = SKAction.sequence([scrollUp, scrollReset])
        let scrollForever = SKAction.repeatForever(scrollLoop)

        background.run(scrollForever)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Your advice helped with aligning the the images and filling the screen, but the loop is still messing up and I can't understand why. Here's a small clip of what's happening. 

https://i.imgur.com/w4TdINY.mp4

The loop isn't stitching together as you can see from the top and the loop is still jumpy. Also, my anchor point is on 0.0 0.0 if that helps.

Comment: I am going to guess it is because of all of the different sizes you have going on.   I would try and simplify your code so that your background and your scene are the same size

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense. Also excuse my ignorance as I'm new to coding, but if I need to have the background the same size as the scene, how would I make it work on all iPhone devices that's not, in this case, iPhone 5S? Have multiple textures of different sizes in my assets library?

Comment: The scene scales to different devices. That is what aspect fill does